# how do i calculate the nomination pool address?

Tags: polkadot-sdk

Im trying to replicate the addresses for a nomination pool so that i can remove it from a snapshot.

```
const { u8aConcat, bnToU8a, stringToU8a } = require('@polkadot/util');
const { blake2AsU8a } = require( '@polkadot/util-crypto');
const { encodeAddress } = require('@polkadot/keyring');


const palletId = new Uint8Array([...Buffer.from('py/nom')]); // guessing py/nom or something like this?
// pool id
const poolId = 19; // example poolid
// prefix, 0 for Polkadot
const prefix = 0;

// create a sub account for the pool
function createSubAccount(palletId, poolId) {
  // AccountType::Bonded is assumed to be 0
  const accountType = new Uint8Array([0x00]);

  // concat palletId, accountType and poolId
  const combined = u8aConcat(palletId, accountType, bnToU8a(poolId, { bitLength: 64, isLe: true }));

  // hash combined data
  const hashed = blake2AsU8a(combined);

  return hashed;
}

// generate the sub-account ID
const subAccountId = createSubAccount(palletId, poolId);

// ss58 format
const ss58Address = encodeAddress(subAccountId, prefix);

console.log(ss58Address);
```

pool 19 is an example:
`13UVJyLnbVp8c4FQeiGDv7fdkw25yW9K6LhfsajWcUPcqPa2`

the above code is of course producing an incorrect id.

i am trying to replicate it and every pool.

Can you show me what i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The PalletId you are looking for is `modlpy/nopls`. Replacing your current `py/nom` with `modlpy/nopls` gives the correct answer